# Unable to get property 'bind' of undefined. Babel 7 + core-js + IE11

Tags: reactjs, typescript, babeljs, internet-explorer-11, core-js

## The Problem

I've been working on a live chat client built in react/typescript for a month or two, it's working great, but we need to add support for Internet explorer 11.

Initially during development I was using Webpack as my build system and as I was using Typescript, I was passing everything through `ts-loader`.

With the need to support `Internet Explorer 11` I decided to change to `babel 7` as there is now good typescript support. I hoped to use babel to polyfill IE11.

I believe I've followed [the project setup guide via babel docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/usage). Yet when testing the project inside IE11 in a virtual machine, I still receive the following error:

**Unabled to get property 'bind' of undefined or null reference.**
[image]

If I expand the error it seems to be tripping up inside a file for a dependency called `load-script`.

[image]

It still works perfectly in all other modern browsers, including Edge, it just seems to be having issues with IE11.

I can't be sure but it seems like it isn't doing anything to the node_modules.

**Information About Setup (I'll include file snippets below):**

- Because I'm using `babel 7` I don't need to use `@babel/polyfill`, instead I'm using `core-js@3.6.5`
- I'm importing `core-js` and `regenerator-runtime/runtime` into the route file.(Although when running `debug: true` in my babel env config. It tells me to remove these imports due to the use of `useBuiltIns: usage`.)

## What I've tried to do

When inspected the errors inside the developer tools, I've traced back the issues to the different dependencies it's complaining about, commented out the imports and temporarily uninstalled. It then complains about another module.

This gives me the impression it isn't working over the imported dependencies. As such I tried removing the `exclude: /node_modules/` from the `webpack.config.js`.

## Code Examples

**package.json**

```
  {
  "name": "@rradar/chat-client",
  "version": "2.2.9",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --no-cache || true",
    "watch": "webpack --watch --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "prettier:base": "prettier --parser typescript --single-quote",
    "prettier:check": "npm run prettier:base -- --list-different \"src/**/*.{ts,tsx}\"",
    "prettier:write": "npm run prettier:base -- --write \"src/**/*.{ts,tsx}\""
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://git.rradar.com/npm-packages/chat-client/issues",
    "email": "adam.bowers@rradar.com"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://git.rradar.com/npm-packages/chat-client"
  },
  "author": "rradar Limited",
  "license": "ISC",
  "contributors": [
    {
      "name": "Adam Bowers",
      "email": "adam.bowers@rradar.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "Tom Hughes",
      "email": "tom.hughes@rradar.com"
    }
  ],
  "jest": {
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/test.setup.js"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      ".scss$": "<rootDir>/config/SCSSStub.js"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/config/test.preprocess.js"
    },
    "testMatch": [
      "**/__tests__/*.(ts|tsx|js)"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome": "^1.1.8",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-solid": "^5.0.13",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.0",
    "@rradar/grace-api": "^2.2.3",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "date-fns": "^1.29.0",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.4",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "howler": "^2.0.14",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.0",
    "mo-js": "^0.288.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "pulltorefreshjs": "^0.1.14",
    "pusher-js": "^4.2.2",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-player": "^2.6.2",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.0",
    "uuid": "^8.2.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.12.1",
    "@types/classnames": "^2.2.7",
    "@types/cordova": "0.0.34",
    "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/howler": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.0",
    "@types/js-cookie": "^2.1.0",
    "@types/lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.3",
    "@types/node": "^10.5.2",
    "@types/pulltorefreshjs": "^0.1.2",
    "@types/pusher-js": "^4.2.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.36",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.6",
    "@types/react-fontawesome": "^1.6.3",
    "@types/react-html-parser": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.9",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^16.0.1",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/window-or-global": "^1.0.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "jest": "^23.4.1",
    "jsdoc": "^3.5.5",
    "lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.0",
    "minami": "^1.2.3",
    "prettier": "^1.13.7",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.4.1",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "stylelint": "^9.3.0",
    "stylelint-order": "^0.8.1",
    "ts-jest": "^23.0.1",
    "ts-loader": "^4.5.0",
    "tslint": "^5.11.0",
    "tslint-react": "^3.6.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.8.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-strip-block": "^0.2.0"
  }
}
```

**babel.config.json**

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "chrome": "58",
          "ie": "11"
        },
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "corejs": {"version": "3.6.5", "proposals": true},
        "debug": true
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react",
    [
      "@babel/preset-typescript",
      {
        "isTSX": true,
        "allExtensions": true
      }
    ]
  ],

  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

**Webpack Config**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = (env, { mode }) => {
  const useBundleAnalyzerPlugin = mode !== 'production' || (env && env.local);

  if (useBundleAnalyzerPlugin) {
    BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer')
      .BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
  }

  return {
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      publicPath: '/',
      library: 'ChatClient',
      libraryTarget: 'amd',
    },
    optimization: {
      usedExports: true,
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    externals: {
      lodash: 'lodash',
      react: 'react',
      reactDOM: 'react-dom',
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          use: 'babel-loader'
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|svg|jpg)$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'file-loader',
              options: {
                emitFile: true,
                name: 'images/[name].[ext]',
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(mp3)$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'url-loader',
              options: {
                limit: 20000,
                fallback: 'file-loader',
              },
            },
          ],
          exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: [
            { loader: 'style-loader' },
            { loader: 'css-loader' },
            { loader: 'resolve-url-loader' },
            { loader: 'sass-loader?sourceMap' },
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.tsx|.ts$/,
          enforce: 'pre',
          exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components|\.spec\.js)/,
          use: [{ loader: 'webpack-strip-block' }],
        },
      ],
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
      alias: {
        'chat-client': path.resolve(__dirname, '../module/dist/main.js'),
        assets: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets'),
      },
      symlinks: true,
    },
    plugins: [
      ...(useBundleAnalyzerPlugin
        ? [
            new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
              openAnalyzer: true,
            }),
          ]
        : []),
    ],
  };
};
```

Comment: It can be possible that you are configuring the Babel incorrectly. I try to check the Babel docs and found that there are several ways to configure Babel. I suggest you refer to this [document](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/configuration) and try to configure the babel as per your requirement that may help to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**How I Fixed The Issue**

After speaking with a colleague it seems they had a similar issue in the past. It was remedied by importing the following into the root file.

Bear in mind **you'll have to install these first.**

```
import 'promise-polyfill/src/polyfill';
import 'whatwg-fetch';
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can avoid adding imports to your code altogether and Webpack can take care of this for you with Babel. I'd recommend this approach which will detect and handle all functions requiring polyfills automatically. This removes the need for you to explicitly and manually identify and include each polyfill in your codebase:

[How to create IE11 Bundles with Webpack 5 and Babel 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65035451/how-to-create-ie11-bundles-with-webpack-5-and-babel-7)