# How to create IE11 Bundles with Webpack 5 and Babel 7

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, internet-explorer-11, babel-loader

How can we compile modern JavaScript into backwards-compatible JavaScript bundles that can be used with Internet Explorer 11 (ie11)?  Specifically, how can we do this with the latest versions of Webpack 5 and Babel 7?

Comment: I created this self-answered question after spending days trying to get this working. Hope it helps others avoid the pain too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's the most minimal configuration I could create, with a test file that's included to test with IE 11. [Download on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/AnthumChris/249d741b64081f88db7938f502855447).

**package.json**

```json
{
  "browserslist": [
    "ie 11"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "dev":   "webpack -w",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.7",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "core-js": "^3.8.0",
    "webpack": "^5.8.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.m?js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: [
            ['@babel/preset-env', {
              useBuiltIns: 'usage',
              corejs: 3
            }]
          ]
        }
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

**Greeting.js**

```js
export default '2020 has been one hell of a year!'
```

**index.js**

```js
/* 
 * Test that uses modern JavaScript and will be compiled to work in IE 11
 */
import greeting from './Greeting'

window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
  const o = {
    greeting: await Promise.resolve(greeting)
  }

  console.log(
    o,
    Object.entries(o),
    Object.keys(o),
    Object.values(o),
  )
})
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question. It will surely help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Configuration is missing "arrowFunction: false"  https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputenvironment to make it work with IE11 and webpack 5

Comment: `browserlist` is implicitly handling that already, true?

Comment: @AnthumChris not the webpack arrows. Open the output file with your exact code exemple, you will find arrows without `"arrowFunction: false"`

Comment: I'm not seeing arrow functions in the generated bundle. Kindly download the Gist above and run the following:
`npm install && npm run build && grep '=>' dist/main.js || echo '✅ No arrow functions exist.'`